# HighCharts: How do I make the stockcharts to snap to latest date

Tags: highcharts

We are evaluating highstock charts to plot data for our reports. Data streams in from our servers in one hour chunks, from oldest to latest. We have configured the range selector to display 1h, 1d and 1w data:

rangeSelector: {
   buttons: [{
   type: 'minute',
                    count: 60,
                    text: '1h'
                },
                {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1d'
                },
                {
                    type: 'week',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1w'
                },
                {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                selected: 0,

By default, highcharts seem to select the first hour of data that is coming in. For example if the data range is 3/20/2015 00:00 - 3/24/2015 00:00, the data that is selected for display is 3/20/2015 00:00 - 01:00.

We would like it to keep displaying the last hour as long as the user doesn't choose 1 day where we would like it to be last day and so on. Is there a property, similar to http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#glueToTheEnd that I can turn ON to do this?

Comment: I think you'll need to explain both the desired result and the problem a bit more.  What do you mean that it "selects the first hour"?

Comment: It would be great to see it live. Your description sounds exactly how Highstock works, see [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line) - Selected is second button (3m) and **last** three months are displayed. So what comes to my mind - check your dataset if you have proper range of values.